# Calculation using prime number theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

Fix a (large) number N and suppose that Bob chooses a random number n
in the interval $1/2N ≤ n ≤ 3/2N$. If he repeats this process many times, prove
that approximately $1/ ln(N)$ of his numbers will be prime. More precisely,
define the probability that an integer n in the interval 1/2N ≤ n ≤ 3/2N is a prime number

$P(N)$ = (number of primes between $1/2N$ and $3/2N$) / (number of integers between $1/2N$ and $3/2N$)

and prove that

$ lim(n to ∞) P(N)/(1/ln(N)) = 1$

This shows that if $N$ is large, then $P(N)$ is approximately $1/ln(N)$.

What I have tried:

$P(N)$ = (π (3/2N) - π(1/2n))/N

```
    = (3/2)/ln(3/2N)-(1/2)/ln(1/2N)  as n goes to ∞
```

How to calculate the next steps in order to get 1/ln(N)?

Comment: When you write $1/2N$ and $3/2N$ it is not clear that you mean $N/2$ and $3N/2$  Parentheses, please, unless you are going to stack the fractions as $\frac N2$ and $\frac {3N}2$

Comment: I agree that parentheses would be helpful, but in this case the unintended reading of $1/(2N)$ and $3/(2N)$ would result in an interval that contains no integers (and thus no primes) once $N\geq2$, so it's clear that it's unintended.

Answer (score 1):

Use that $\ln(\frac32N)=\ln(\frac32)+\ln N$ and similarly for the other denominator.  Then use that, for any constant $a$ (like $\ln\frac32$ or $\ln\frac12$), the ratio 
$$
\frac{a+\ln N}{\ln N }
$$
approaches $1$ as $N\to\infty$.